# Setting bootstrap navbar active element using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my Navbar I have:

```
<ul class="nav" >            
          <li class="active"><?php echo anchor('b/home', 'Home') ?></li>
          <li><?php echo anchor('buyers/info', 'Information') ?></li>
```

I want to set the class active depending on the page I'm on. I have passed in the name of the inner html as a variable called 'nav'. To this I want to select "The 'li' element where the contained 'a' element's inner HTML= value of 'nav' "

I'm not experienced at jquery. I've tried the following, but it does not work:

```
$("li [a[html()=nav]]").addClass('active');
```

Could someone give me a hand in fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

```
$('li a:contains("' + nav + '")').parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Prolly forgot to `' + nav + '`?

Comment: Uhm... yeah... if 'nav' is just a reference to some other value.

Answer (score 3):

why not conditionally echo the active class using php? at the top of your php files make a variable called $page and set it to the name of whatever page you're on. Then do:

```
<li class="<?php if ($page == "some page") echo "active"; ?>"><?php echo anchor('b/home', 'Home') ?></li>
```

Comment: I actually am going to use your method - Thanks